# Getting error: Target class must declare a method with matching name and parameter types

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have declared a job in `batch_context.xml`:

```
<bean id="Daily" class="com.myapps.framework.batch.TaskletAdapter" scope="step">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="jobService" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="runBatch" />
    <property name="arguments">
    <list>
    <value>null</value>
    <value>#{jobParameters[date]}</value>
    <value>INR</value>
    </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<job:job id="DailyBatch">
<job:step id="DailyBatchStep">
       <job:tasklet ref="Daily">
            <job:transaction-attributes propagation="NOT_SUPPORTED" />
        </job:tasklet>
        <job:listeners>
            <job:listener ref="BatchListener" />
        </job:listeners>
    </job:step>
</job:job>
```

and inside the java class I am setting date inside `jobParameters` and triggering the job.

My target service definetion is:

```
jobService.runBatch(String id,Date date,String currencyCode)
```

Why is it throwing me an exception that target method parameters don't match?

Comment: try passing `null` as `date` first. `#{...}` denotes expression that ought to be evaluated and value of which gets passed as parameter to the bean.

Comment: @diginoise: NO, getting same issue with null also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to quote the word `date` in it's reference in the job parameters injection. My bet is that you're just getting a `String` injected for that instead of the `Date` you're expecting.  Try `#jobParameters['date']}`.